# Ler JSON com Delphi 6

Tags: json, delphi

Tenho um arquivo JSON, porém gostaria lê-lo usando Delphi 6. Seria possível?

Segue um exemplo do JSON

```
{
   "size":1,
   "response":[
      {
         "id_cliente":21,
         "nome":"DESENTUPIDORA ME",
         "endereco":"RUA J, Nº. 9",
         "complemento":"TÉRREO ",
         "bairro":"SANTOS",
         "cidade":"VITÓRIA",
         "estado":"ES",
         "cep":"29.000-000",
         "telefone":"28-18987677",
         "telefone_fax":"28-9878-08685",
         "email":"desentupidornelio@hotmail.com",
         "cnpj":"098873.835/0033-87",
         "pesagem_livre":0,
         "nome_fantasia":"DESENTUPIDORA SJOE -ME",
         "tipo_cliente":"privado",
         "inscricao_estadual":"",
         "situacao":true,
         "inscricao_municipal":"",
         "periodo_medicao":"9931",
         "anotacoes":"",
         "data_inclusao":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Daniel, não consigo formular uma resposta por falta de tempo, mas pesquisa sobre SuperObject para Delphi6, é uma biblioteca que você conseguira fazer o que quer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar o [json4delphi](https://github.com/rilyu/json4delphi), que possui as rotinas para Delphi 6 ou superior. No link do GitHub possui um exemplo de uso, mas vou replicá-lo aqui:

```
var
  Json: TJson;
  Str: String
begin
  Json := TJson.Create();

  //put
  Json.Put('field1', null);
  Json.Put('field2', True);
  Json.Put('field3', 3.14);
  Json.Put('field4', 'hello world');

  //another way
  Json['field5'].AsBoolean := False;
  Json['field6'].AsString := 'hello world';

  //object
  with Json['field7'].AsObject do
  begin
    Put('subfield1', 2.7182818284);
    Put('subfield2', 'json4delphi');
  end;

  //array
  with Json['field8'].AsArray do
  begin
    Put(6.6260755e-34);
    Put('The magic words are squeamish ossifrage');
  end;

  //get
  Str := Json['field4'].AsString;

  //parse
  Json.Parse('{"a":1}');

  //stringify
  Str := Json.Stringify;
end;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção vou tentar usar.